# Why does peek return unexpected results in my circular linked list?

Tags: rust, linked-list

I'm attempting to implement a circular linked list in Rust. I've read [Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) and multiple resources on the Rust Pin type, and I've attempted to build a circular linked list from scratch and I'm getting baffled at what the compiler spits out.

So the high-level concept is I want a linked list struct and node struct defined as followed:

```
  use std::pin::Pin;
  use std::marker::PhantomPinned;
  use std::ptr;

  #[derive(Debug)]
  struct Node<T> {
      value: T,
      next: *mut Node<T>,
      _pin: PhantomPinned,
  }

  #[derive(Debug)]
  pub struct CircularLinkedList<T> {
    last: *mut Node<T>,
    size: usize
  }
```

For the first node to be pushed into the list, I want node.next to point to the node struct itself. i.e. I want the logic for pushing a new node on the list to follow the following Java implementation

```java
    public void push(Item item) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.item = item;

        if (isEmpty()) {
            last = node;
            last.next = last;
        } else {
            node.next = last.next;
            last.next = node;
            last = node;
        }
        size++;
    }
```

The Rust implementation I have so far is:

```
  impl<T> CircularLinkedList<T> where T: std::fmt::Debug {
      pub fn new() -> Self {
        CircularLinkedList { last: ptr::null_mut(), size: 0 }
      }

      pub fn enqueue(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.size = self.size + 1;

        if self.last.is_null() {
          
          let new_last = Node {
            value,
            next: ptr::null_mut(),
            _pin: PhantomPinned,
          };

          // Pin new node
          let mut pinned_new_last = Box::pin(new_last);

          // Get raw pointer to new node
          let ptr = pinned_new_last.as_ref().get_ref() as *const Node<T> as *mut Node<T>;
          
          // Assign next new_last.next value of 'ptr'
          unsafe {
              let mut_ref: Pin<&mut Node<T>> = Pin::as_mut(&mut pinned_new_last);
              Pin::get_unchecked_mut(mut_ref).next = ptr;
          }

          self.last = ptr;

        }
        else {
          println!("else");
        }        

      }

      pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        unsafe {
          let a = &(*self.last).value;
          Some(a)
        }
      }
}
```

In the following main() function, I'm baffled as to why peek() doesn't return `Some(1)` and miri gives me a memory error

```
fn main () {
  let mut list = LinkedList::CircularLinkedList::new();
  list.enqueue(1);
  println!("{:?}", list.peek());
  // Some(2043) !????????, expecting Some(1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning:** You should not write `unsafe` code unless you completely understand all details of it! (experimentation is fine, though).

---

You got a Use-After-Free. At the end of `enqueue()`, the destructor of `Box` is executed for `pinned_new_last` and frees its memory. Now your linked list points to freed node. Adding `std::mem::forget()` is enough in this case:

```rust
pub fn enqueue(&mut self, value: T) {
    self.size = self.size + 1;

    if self.last.is_null() {
        let new_last = Node {
            value,
            next: ptr::null_mut(),
            _pin: PhantomPinned,
        };

        // Pin new node
        let mut pinned_new_last = Box::pin(new_last);

        // Get raw pointer to new node
        let ptr = pinned_new_last.as_ref().get_ref() as *const Node<T> as *mut Node<T>;

        // Assign next new_last.next value of 'ptr'
        unsafe {
            let mut_ref: Pin<&mut Node<T>> = Pin::as_mut(&mut pinned_new_last);
            Pin::get_unchecked_mut(mut_ref).next = ptr;
        }
        
        std::mem::forget(pinned_new_last);

        self.last = ptr;
    } else {
        println!("else");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e65033ac02708ce526faa8acea8088c3).

Of course it leaks the memory. You have to take care to free it in the destructor, something like:

```rust
impl<T> Drop for CircularLinkedList<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut last = self.last;
        let size = self.size;
        
         // Panic safety
        self.size = 0;
        self.last = std::ptr::null_mut();
        
        for _ in 0..size {
            let current = last;
            unsafe {
                last = (*last).next;
                Box::from_raw(current); // Drop it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that while *storing* the node as `*mut` pointer is sound, actually *mutating* it is UB as it was derived from a shared reference, so this is really a code smell.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and helpful response!

Comment: "experimentation is fine, though" still risky, experimenting with unsafe and going off of *observable behaviour* (rather than reasoning) is very unreliable, because as soon as you step into UB land observations become entirely conditional and not globally applicable: whether and how the compiler will mangle the code depends on everything else in the codebase. When using unsafe, running miri is *necessary* (but not even remotely sufficient). Here, miri trivially flags the UAF in `peek`.

Comment: @Masklinn Of course, I meant experimentation as part of the learning process, but not as the learning process alone.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken some time to learn more about Rust and was able to come up with the following implemention that doesn't throw any miri errors

```
pub mod LinkedList {
  use std::marker::PhantomPinned;
  use std::ptr;
  use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;

  // _pin -> make the struct implement !Unpin, and make it pinnable
  #[derive(Debug)]
  struct Node<T> where T: std::fmt::Debug {
      value: T,
      next: *mut Node<T>,
      _pin: PhantomPinned,
  }

  #[derive(Debug)]
  pub struct CircularLinkedList<T> where T: std::fmt::Debug {
    last: *mut Node<T>,
    size: usize
  }

  impl<T> CircularLinkedList<T> where T: std::fmt::Debug {
      pub fn new() -> Self {
        CircularLinkedList { last: ptr::null_mut(), size: 0 }
      }

      pub fn enqueue(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.size = self.size + 1;

        // Create a new Node struct, assign it to new_last variable
        // Struct - no guarantees on data layout
        let new_last = Node {
          value,
          next: ptr::null_mut(),
          _pin: PhantomPinned,
        };
        
        // Construct a new <Pin<Box<T>>>
        // new_last is pinned in heap, and can't move from this address
        // pinned_new_last is Pin<Box<T>> type - a smart pointer
        // Wrap in ManuallyDrop - 0-cost wrapper that stop compiler from calling destructor for pinned_new_last
        // When Pin<Box<T>> dropped, both the pointer and pointee dropped, so need to clean this up in the drop
        let mut pinned_new_last = ManuallyDrop::new(Box::pin(new_last));

        if self.last.is_null() {          
          unsafe {
            // as_mut gets Pin<Box<Node>> => Pin<&mut Node>
            // get_unchecked_mut gets Pin<&mut Node> => &mut Node
            // We coerce it into a *mut T
            pinned_new_last.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut().next = pinned_new_last.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut() as *mut Node<T>; 
            self.last = pinned_new_last.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut() as *mut Node<T>;
          }
        } else {
          unsafe {
            pinned_new_last.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut().next = (*self.last).next; 
            (*self.last).next = pinned_new_last.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut() as *mut Node<T>;
            self.last = pinned_new_last.as_mut().get_unchecked_mut() as *mut Node<T>;
          }
        }        

      }

      pub fn dequeue(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.last.is_null() {None} 
        else {
          self.size = self.size - 1;

          unsafe {

            // This fixed the memory leak!!!
            // Let Box destructor call destructor of T and free allocated memory
            let last = Box::from_raw(self.last);
            if self.size == 0 {self.last = ptr::null_mut();}
            else {self.last = last.next;}
            let value = (*last).value;
            Some(value)
          }
        }
      }        

      pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        
        if self.last.is_null() {None}

        else {
          unsafe {
            // Deref self.last (it is a *mut Node)
            // Get value field
            // Cast entire thing to &
            Some(&(*self.last).value)
          }
        }
        
      }
    }

    impl<T> Drop for CircularLinkedList<T> where T: std::fmt::Debug  {
      fn drop(&mut self) {
        while let Some(_) = self.dequeue() {}
      }
    }

}

fn main () {
  let mut list = LinkedList::CircularLinkedList::new();
  list.enqueue(1);
  list.enqueue(2);
  list.dequeue();
  list.dequeue();
  println!("{:?}", list.peek());
}
```